# Intl.NumberFormat either 0 or two fraction digits

Tags: javascript

My formatter looks like this

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-NZ', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'NZD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});
```

How can I adjust this so that whole numbers have 0 fraction digits

```
formatter.format(4); // want output "$4"
```

whilst fractions always show two digits?

```
formatter.format(4.1); // want output "$4.10"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### 2023 Answer

A new `Intl.NumberFormat` option [trailingZeroDisplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#trailingzerodisplay) can be used to strip the fraction digits *if* the fraction digits are all zero, otherwise the minimum and maximum fraction digit options will be used.  This duplicates the behavior of the answers using two formatters with only a single formatter

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-NZ', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'NZD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
  trailingZeroDisplay: 'stripIfInteger'
});
```

```
formatter.format(4); // outputs "$4"
formatter.format(4.0); // outputs "$4"
formatter.format(4.1); // outputs "$4.10"
formatter.format(4.145); // outputs "$4.15"
```

Answer (score 75):

The correct way to do it when using Intl.NumberFormat is to set both *maximumFractionDigits* and *minimumFractionDigits* options in constructor while validating input value using a modulo % for a whole number (per https://stackoverflow.com/a/49724586/1362535 **which is a CORRECT answer**!). The accepted answer is sort of string manipulation.

```js
const fraction = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-NZ', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'NZD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  maximumFractionDigits: 0,
});

const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-NZ', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'NZD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});

let number = 4.1;
  if(number % 1 == 0)
console.log(fraction.format(number));
  else
console.log(formatter.format(number));

number = 4;
  if(number % 1 == 0)
console.log(fraction.format(number));
  else
console.log(formatter.format(number));
```

Comment: Using minimum and maximum Fraction Digits is the correct way when using Intl.NumberFormat

Comment: There is no option `maximumFractionDigits` which exists.

Comment: @Acidic9 have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat

Comment: @Acidic9 did you try to only use `maximumFractionDigits`? I found it gives an error you do not use both.

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where the formatting results in an integer. 1234.999 would result in 1235,00

Comment: @olefrank it does. with both min and max set to 0, it results in an integer.

Answer (score 33):

You could try something like this:

```
formatter.format(amount).replace(/\D00$/, '');
```

Update:

In response to the many-months-later comment by @Marek, the above regex already handles differing decimal symbols (either `.` or `,`), but it's true that it doesn't handle trailing currency symbols. That can be fixed this way:

```
formatter.format(amount).replace(/\D00(?=\D*$)/, '');
```

Comment: The proposed solution won't work in some locales where formatter appends instead of prepends the currency code/symbol. For example `sk` locale and `EUR` currency produce `12,50 €`. Plus you need to consider different fraction separators (comma, dot).

In that case, you could use [formatToParts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/formatToParts) instead of the `format` method which produces an array where each fragment is uniquely identified. Then all you need to do is conditionally filter out the `fraction` and `decimal` fragments.

Comment: Just a question, for en-us locale, why would you need a regex? Isn't ``.replace('.00', '') `` simply enough?

Comment: @ViBoNaCci, yes, if you didn't care about handling other locales, you could do without the regex. The regex is meant to deal with either a dot or a comma as a decimal symbol.

Comment: @ViBoNaCci also careful with straight replace, because it will replace that anywhere in the number, not just at the end.

Comment: @JordanMorris True. But in en-us, dot is decimal separate so that replace should be waterproof, given its only for en-us.

Answer (score 25):

I would implement two different formats and validate it using a modulo `%`

```
4 % 1 == 0
4.1 % 1 == .1
```

Hope this helps :)

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-NZ', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'NZD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});

const fraction = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-NZ', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'NZD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
});


let number = 4.1;
  if(number % 1 == 0)
console.log(fraction.format(number));
  else
console.log(formatter.format(number));


number = 4;
  if(number % 1 == 0)
console.log(fraction.format(number));
  else
console.log(formatter.format(number));
```

Comment: Seems like the safest option

Comment: This example doesn't achieve the goal of the asker:  "either 0 or two fraction digits"

Comment: It does, you can try out and edit the `number` on the snippet to see the functionality

Answer (score 15):

When I researched this, I found a posting on Github about it that suggests using both the maximumFractionDigits and the minimumFractionDigits. The article states that if both are not used, it would throw an error.

```
// works
var Intl = require('intl');
new Intl.NumberFormat("en", { 
  maximumFractionDigits: 0, 
  minimumFractionDigits: 0, 
  style: 'currency', 
  currency: 'USD'
}).format(4000.33)
```

https://github.com/ember-intl/ember-intl/issues/167

Answer (score 3):

**Update: See @yoduh's answer, mine doesn't quite answer the question.**

It seems that today, the easiest way is to simply set "minimumFractionDigits" to 0, and "maximumFractionDigits" to 2, like this:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'usd',
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
}); 

console.log('No decimals: ', formatter.format(1000));
console.log('Decimals: ', formatter.format(999.99));
```

Comment: This doesn't technically meet the original requirement of `formatter.format(4.1)` returning an output value of `4.10`, it just returns `4.1`

Comment: @yoduh You're right, I've changed my answer to redirect to yours.