# convert number to millions with two decimal point in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

how to convert the number into million formats with two decimal points I tried with this code.
My Input is `milFormate(1000);`

```
milFormate(value){
  var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat();
  return nf.format(value).toLocaleString();
}
```

my output is `10,100`

I expected should be `10,100.00` how can I achieve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Also Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724537/intl-numberformat-either-0-or-two-fraction-digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `minimumFractionDigits` option in order to achieve that:

```
function milFormate(value){
  var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumFractionDigits: 2  });
  return nf.format(value);
}
```